# Thread getName() returns wrong name

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Ok, I know it's probabblly mz bad understanding of how threads really work, but until someone helps me understand I'll believe that it's a bug :)

In my Main class and its main() method I have:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    StoneBucket stoneBucket = new StoneBucket();    
    StonePutter spRunnable   = new StonePutter(stoneBucket);
    StoneThrower stRunnable  = new StoneThrower(stoneBucket);
    StoneThrower stRunnable2 = new StoneThrower(stoneBucket);

    //Create the Threads that will take the Runnables as arguments
    Thread puttingThread = new Thread(spRunnable);
    Thread throwingThread = new Thread(stRunnable);
    Thread throwingThread2 = new Thread(stRunnable);

    puttingThread.setName("Putter");
    throwingThread.setName("Thrower 1");
    throwingThread2.setName("Thrower 2");
    [...]
```

And then in my StoneThrower class I have

```
public class StoneThrower implements Runnable{

private StoneBucket sb;
private String name;

public StoneThrower(StoneBucket _sb){
    this.sb = _sb;
}   

public void run(){

    name = Thread.currentThread().getName();        
    System.out.println("T::"+name+" started...");       
    int count = 0;      
    while(true){
            [...]
```

When I compile and run this code I'm getting:

[image: Screenshot of 2 threads...]

So, my question is why do both of these threads return the same name for `currentThread().getName()` ?
When they were created they were assigned the name through `threadX.setName("XXX")` and those runnables are started by calling `threadX.start()`...
Could someone please clarify me this?

EDIT: I accepted the correct answer because changing the stRunnable to stRunnable2 the behaviour is as expected. The real question is now why does this happen. I create two threads and start them separately. How is it posibble that the run() method (called once when the thread's created) returns wrong name ?

Comment: Can you post the bit of code where you are starting the threads?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because you store thread name in instance variable `name` of your `StoneThrower`. Because of concurrency, second thread overrides value of `name` that first thread has just set and both of them output the same value.

Here is your scenario:

```
1. Thread1#start
2. Thread2#start
3. Thread1#runnable#run -> runnable.name = 'Thrower 1'
4. Thread2#runnable#run -> runnable.name = 'Thrower 2' // overrides
5. Thread1#runnable#run -> System.out.println(runnable.name)
6. Thread2#runnable#run -> System.out.println(runnable.name)
```

Comment: Finally a reasonable diagnosis. +1

Comment: I added a comment asking this. Thank you so much and sorry @NPE for taking the correct answer flag :(

Comment: Have not seen the whole implementation of `StoneThrower` but most probably you can have only one instance of it if you convert `name` to local variable.

Answer (score 5):

You create both threads with the same runnable:

```
Thread throwingThread = new Thread(stRunnable);
Thread throwingThread2 = new Thread(stRunnable);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^ stRunnable2?
```

You store the thread name in an instance variable of the `Runnable` object. Since the object is shared by the two threads, the second thread to execute `name = Thread.currentThread().getName()` overwrites the first thread's name with its own.

Comment: Creating separate threads with the same Runnable in itself does not force the threads to have the same name. Something else is going on.

Comment: @TedHopp: In this instance, it does. Thread name is stored in an instance variable of the `Runnable` object. Since the object is shared by the two threads, the second thread to execute `name = Thread.currentThread().getName()` wins.

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't part of your answer when I made that comment. With the edit, it now earns my +1.

Comment: @NPE.. Actually you should also remove the first part, as it has nothing to do with the result.

Comment: I feel ashamed now :( Can we remove it, please ?

Comment: @RohitJain: Oh yes it does.

Comment: @RohitJain - The first part is relevant. If the threads were created with separate `Runnable` instances, there wouldn't have been a name overwrite.

Comment: I think @TedHopp's answer makes sense. We're naming the Thread object that was created. The name is not set on the runnable object... THe weird thing is that when in the run method I print the thread's name directly I get more often the T1, T2 result and if I do assignation to the  name variable first I get mor of T2, T2